# Motion Trail effect in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, effects

I'm looking for a way to create a motion trail effect very similar to this one:
[image]

I've been searching for some time without a solution.

My first thought was to create 'clones' and modify them (blur, scale, etc) but that doesn't seem very efficient to me.

Another thought was to use an SKEmitterNode but I have no Idea which properties/values would work best for this kind of effect.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Try playing around with the emitter's life span values.

Comment: emitter or custom shader would work

Answer (score 1):

> My first thought was to create 'clones' and modify them (blur, scale, etc) but that doesn't seem very efficient to me.

I think this is the only way. 
I've used this and I've seen others do it too.

I doubt it's much less efficient than using SKEmitterNode.

Comment: It is certianly less efficient than using SKEmitterNode because particles are light-weight objects and doesn't have many properties which can be found on SKSpriteNode... But still, SpriteKit is capable of rendering many nodes in a single draw pass, so I doubt something like this can have big impact on performance.